# Updating UIView with data of another Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, object

I have a `classA` and a `classB`, 
I want to pass data from the `classB` and update an existing `UIView` of an instance of the `classA`.

What I'm doing is instantiating classA in classB and then calling updateLabel:

```
ClassA *obj = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[obj updateView:value];
```

It's not working ! 
I think that it is because updateLabel is called on another instance of `ClassA` where this `UIView` is `nil`. Am I right?

What is the good way to make this work?

ps: I'm doing it this way because the value to update is set when a certain method of `ClassB` is triggered.

Comment: You're right, it is not the right instance. Do you know how you created the first instance ? Do you use interface builder ?

Comment: my first instance is a UIViewController instantiated with storyboard.

Comment: How do you update the label from the method "updateView"?. Is it calling actually? Put a breakpoint there and check if the label is nil or not.

Comment: Could you show some more code?

Comment: Yes, the method is actually called and the parameter passed.

Comment: @SanchoSanchez, see my answer there u can pass the parameters also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the data in class A you can use NSNotificationCenter or delegate

in Class A at the time of initialisation.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(labelUpdate:) name:@"NoficationName" object:nil];
}

-(void)labelUpdate:(id)sender{
     //do your update stuff.
}
```

call in Class B when you want to update the Class A

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NoficationName" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of create an instance of classA in classB It's some what better to use `NSNotificationcenter`.
From **ClassB** send some notification to **ClassA** with some notification name like 
 **[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"upDateLabel" object:nil];**

In **classB** add an Observer for the notification as well as add the target for that like

**[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(`yourTargetedMethod`) name:@"upDateLabel" object:self];**

For more details about NSNotification [click Here](http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You are right you try call another instance of ClassA.

You can achieve this by passing ClassA as a parameter to ClassB, something like that:

```
@interface ClassB : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) ClassA classA;

//.. other stuff
@end
```

After that when you create ClassB just pass ClassA to it:

```
ClassA myClassA = [ClassA new];
//set up class a here

ClassB classB = [ClassB new];
classB.classA = myClassA;
```

and in ClassB you can call update on classA:

```
[self.classA updateView:value];
```

Comment: The problem is that i'm not instantiating classB from classA